# What really happened to civilization in Alita: Battle Angel?

Tags: alita-battle-angel

In the movie we are told that

> there was a war against the Martians that destroyed a lot of civilization on the surface of the planet and all but one of the floating cities.

We are also told that

> Alita is built with Martian technology.

But Alita eventually remembers that

> she originally used to fight against the floating cities and Nova, who lives in the remaining floating city and does evil experiments on humans.

So I’m confused. What caused all the destruction? Or in other words

> who actually fought who?

Comment: Are you OK with answers based on lore from the manga and/or video game?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Absolutely. The movie alone clearly leaves backstory out.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-hill  Your question confuses me, since Earth is a ball of rock 8,000 miles wide that has to be shattered into many pieces to be destroyed, but the synopsis in Wikipeda says that Earth is so very, very much not destroyed that it still has breathable air and humans living on it.  Thus the disaster must have been much less severe than the one that wiped out the dinosaurs, for example.  You should be more accurate in your choice of words.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Not sure my meaning was really all that unclear, but I’ve updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what the movie back story is, if one exists, but in the manga version the series *Battle Angel Alita: Last Order* explains that Earth was devastated by a "Geo Catastrophe" in 2012. This was an asteroid impact near Japan that caused massive devastation and a decades long ice age that nearly wiped out humanity.

https://battleangel.fandom.com/wiki/Geo_Catastrophe

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Angel_Alita:_Last_Order#Setting

Comment: Oh, wow. Ok, reading through some of that wiki, I found this page, which is the closest parallel to the event in the movie that I alluded to in my question. It sounds like the movie backstory is VASTLY simplified. Therefore I’m probably barking up the wrong tree looking for any real explanation at all. https://battleangel.fandom.com/wiki/Operation_Maulwurf

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Wow. Backstory is the most interesting part of the movie, but it turns out it's A) created specifically for the movie, B) unfinished and vague. I'm not sure whether I'm more mad about that or the fact that [cliffhanger ending seems to be a deliberate choice by movie makers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205928/how-does-the-alita-battle-angel-manga-end).