# How does the "Alita: Battle Angel" manga end?

Tags: manga, alita-battle-angel

I never read the manga but I have just watched the movie and now I'm curious about the next part of story. How does it continue? And, how does the first two arcs (Alita battle angel and last order) end?

> The movie ends with Hugo death.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you read the manga and found out for yourself, rather than having us summarise it for you? Is there any reason you can't or won't do this?

Comment: I didn't watch the movie nor did I read the manga, but if you're looking for what happens after a specific scene, I suggest you [edit] in what said scene is. If you're worried about spoilers, you can hide them by preceding them with `>!`, for instance `>! It turns out Darth Vader was Luke's father`.

Comment: @F1Krazy I don't have time, I'm just curious about it because I appreciated 2 hours movie. No other particular reason :-) if you don't want to help, never mind! Thank you anyway, have a good day!

Comment: I believe it's still continuing. Or do you just mean the first Arc?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yes I meant the ended arcs, Alita Battle Angel and last order.

Comment: In the comics the timeline is different. Alita fights Makuka in the underworld before she ever meets Yugo. He dies the same way and then Alita decides to become an Motoball champion afterwards.

Comment: @Valorum thank you. And then? xD

Comment: @BruceWayne - And then she interacts with various characters you've never heard of and does things you wouldn't understand because the movie has diverged so heavily from the comics

Comment: @Valorum Clear. I wanted to know if she will defeat Nova or not. I don't care too much in how she will interact with some characters like the dog or others.  ^^

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I was confused whether ending the movie on a cliffhanger was a deliberate choice by the movie makers, or one forced by the manga ending on a clifhanger.

Comment: @Dragomok let's see if someone will answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to compare the movie with the manga because some key points are different, but I will try to summarize.

> The main differences in the movie and the manga is that Nova isn't in Zalem, and that the story we saw in the movie is actually 3 stories in the manga.
>
> In the manga the story is divided like this:
>
> story 1: Alita is found and rebuild by Ido (He is from Zalem, no wife or daughter exist/existed). Alita gets the berzerker body and it ends with Alita fighting the big guy from the movie and we get a hint about Nova existing.
>
> story 2: Alita is an experienced Hunter-warrior, and during a raid she meets Hugo. He is a criminal harvesting spines but she doesn't know that. She falls in love, he gets discovered, and the story happens like in the movie. His head gets cut off, he gets a robot body, and he dies climbing to Zalem.
>
> story 3: Alita became depressed after losing Hugo, leaves Ido to join the motorball league. (what is next might actually be a spoiler for an upcoming Alita movie).
>   She challenges the champion for a fight because of martial artist pride or something, builds a team, and fights the champion in an epic character-defining fight. Another hint to Nova in that he made the champion better with brain altering nano-tech.
>
> After this Alita becomes a hunter-warrior again and crazy stuff happens because of Zappan and his revenge. I can expand on this if you want, but basically a huge fight happens, Alita is forced to work for Zalem to track Nova down and bring him back to Zalem, she meets a bunch of cool people (including a new actually interesting boyfriend), and meets Nova in his stronghold somewhere. Here the story branches into two. The writer became deathly ill at this point and created an ending for the story in case he died. There is a continuation of the story if you ignore the last couple of chapters in the original manga (for anybody reading, after Alita gets blown up by the kid robot, switch to the next manga).
>
> This is basically what happens in the first manga series. The next one is *way* too complicated to explain in short. I do recommend reading it because it's awesome and the fights become better and grander.